# How to sort Dictionary by keys where values are array of objects in Swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have Dictionary which contains **String** keys and Array of **Objects** as value. These values are added from the sorted Array of objects into Dictionary using **append** method. The values are categorized into keys based on the first letter of object property. But returns unsorted Dictionary.

The dictionaries are declared:

`var namesDic = [String: [Name]]()`

`var filteredNames = [String: [Name]]()`

And iterating through array and appending into Dictionary:

```
for name in names {
        let letterIndex = name.getName().index(name.getName().startIndex, offsetBy: 0)

        let letter = name.getName()[letterIndex]

        if namesDic[String(letter)] != nil {
            namesDic[String(letter)]?.append(name)
        } else {
            namesDic[String(letter)] = [name]
        }
    }
    filteredNames = namesDic

}
```

Name structure:

```
struct Name {
    var id: Int!
    var name: String!
    var native: String!
    var meaning: String!
    var origin: String!
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var gender: String!

    init(id: Int, name: String, native: String, meaning: String, origin: String, isFavorite: Int, gender: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.native = native
        self.meaning = meaning
        self.origin = origin
        if isFavorite == 0 {
            self.isFavorite = false
        } else { self.isFavorite = true }
        self.gender = gender
    }
}
```

I found in debugging that they are unsorted when they are appended to dictionary. I understand sort on Swift Dictionary is not working but I want a work around to sort Dictionary by key to pass it to TableView.

I went through many questions/answers here but they are all for `[String: String]` not **Array of Objects**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46940363/2303865 If your names array input it is unsorted just sort it before creating your dictionary. Btw you should post your `Name` object structure/class

Comment: @LeoDabus I get the following error after sorting and assigning: `Cannot assign value of type '[(key: String, value: [Name])]' to type '[String : [Name]]'`

Comment: post your Name structure/class declaration

Comment: @LeoDabus Added in the question. Thanks

Comment: first remove all the implicitly unwrapped optionals and make the properties constants

Comment: and change no need to use an Int to initialize your Bool. Btw structures provide its own initializers you don't need to create one most of the time `struct Name {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let native: String
    let meaning: String
    let origin: String
    let isFavorite: Bool
    let gender: String
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks I changed this.

Comment: @MaihamNijat check my post

Comment: Btw if isFavorite is coming from a JSON just cast it to Bool instead of casting it to Int

Comment: All var, all implicitly unwrapped optionals. That's a huge red flag.

Comment: @Alexander Actually IMO `var` is the correct default for structure properties (but `let` is indeed the correct default in every other case). It delegates the mutability to the user of the structure (whether they use `let` or `var`). `let` should only really be used if there are internal invariants that need to be maintained, which doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: Good thread on the matter: https://twitter.com/UINT_MIN/status/921557907719598080

Comment: Note that the types of some of your properties can be improved here – `gender` should almost certainly be an enumeration, and `id` probably shouldn't be an `Int` (does it make sense to add two ids together? should a name ID be the same type as other ID types in your program?). [Rob's advise here is great](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S6UOrwS-Tg&feature=youtu.be&t=17m14s) – create a nested `ID` type.

Comment: @Hamish Sorry, could you elaborate why `var` is preferable? I don't understand "It delegates the mutability to the user of the structure". In this case, I would have preferred `let`, because changing any one of these values would necessarily require the others to change as well, at which point it's better just instantiate a new struct, instead.

Comment: @Alexander It's a little difficult to say what some of the properties in OP's structure actually represent (e.g `meaning` and `native`), but for the most part, I'd say that it probably makes perfect sense for a single property to be mutated without changing others (e.g `isFavorite`). But consider what changing them to `let` would actually get you – well, you wouldn't be able to enforce any additional preconditions, because, well the structure has an initialiser that accepts all values! You just get a (quite a bit) more verbosity if you want to perform a mutation....

Comment: ...And of course, because we're dealing with value types, we don't have to worry about shared mutable state, so I really don't see the argument that it's preferable to go through the initialiser to make one simple mutation (or even mutations to two or three properties). By using `var` as the default, you get the most flexibility – you leave it up to the consumer of the type to decide if they want a given value of that type to be constant or mutable....

Comment: ...But of course, `let` still has its place in structures; you wouldn't be able to enforce certain preconditions without it – but in quite a lot of cases (including this one), structures don't come with preconditions, they're just a bag of values.

Comment: @Hamish Oh yes actually, I agree that `isFavorite` should be a `var`. My prior comment was relating to something like `name`, which gives this entire struct its identity. If you change it, none of the other fields would make sense. `well, you wouldn't be able to enforce any additional preconditions, because, well the structure has an initialiser that accepts all values!` Could you elaborate on this? I don't see why immutability prohibits you from enforcing preconditions. That seems like the perfect use-case for a failable initializer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158433/discussion-between-hamish-and-alexander).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct Name: CustomStringConvertible {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let native: String
    let meaning: String
    let origin: String
    let isFavorite: Bool
    let gender: String
    var description: String {
        return "Id: " + String(id) + " - Name: " + name 
    }
}

let name1 = Name(id: 1, name: "Tim Cook", native: "native", meaning: "meaning", origin: "origin", isFavorite: true, gender: "Male")
let name2 = Name(id: 2, name: "Steve Jobs", native: "native", meaning: "meaning", origin: "origin", isFavorite: true, gender: "Male")
let name3 = Name(id: 3, name: "Tiger Woods", native: "native", meaning: "meaning", origin: "origin", isFavorite: true, gender: "Male")
let name4 = Name(id: 4, name: "Socrates", native: "native", meaning: "meaning", origin: "origin", isFavorite: true, gender: "Male")

let names = [name1, name2, name3, name4]


let dictionary = names.sorted(by: {$0.name < $1.name }).reduce(into: [String: [Name]]()) { result, element in
    // make sure there is at least one letter in your string else return
    guard let first = element.name.first else { return }
    // create a string with that initial
    let initial = String(first)
    // initialize an array with one element or add another element to the existing value
    result[initial, default: []].append(element)
}
```

---

```
let sorted = dictionary.sorted {$0.key < $1.key}
print(sorted)   // "[(key: "S", value: [Id: 4 - Name: Socrates, Id: 2 - Name: Steve Jobs]), (key: "T", value: [Id: 3 - Name: Tiger Woods, Id: 1 - Name: Tim Cook])]\n"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Why not just use [`Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919592-init)?

Comment: Note you can say `result[initial, default: []].append(element)` instead of `result[initial] = (result[initial] ?? []) + [element]` :) Also see [my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148473/how-to-sort-dictionary-by-keys-where-values-are-array-of-objects-in-swift-4#comment81261919_47148473).

Comment: @Hamish I know already https://stackoverflow.com/a/47019843/2303865 I just forgot to change the code that was already implemented in the linked question  but thanks anyway

Comment: @LeoDabus No worries :) If you're interested – `subscript(_:default:)` will actually still cause a copy of the underlying array each time `append(_:)` is called on it (you [could optimise by removing and appending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154903/2976878)), but [I'm trying to get that changed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/12752) such that the underlying array *can* be mutated directly through `subscript(_:default:)`.

Comment: @Hamish I am trying to implement a mutating method to append to a dictionary where the value is a collection but I am getting an error when trying to removeValue(forKey). The error says **Cannot invoke 'removeValue' with an argument list of type '(forKey: K)'** Do you know what constrain I am suppose to use and if this is possible to be accomplished? https://www.dropbox.com/s/qth8eerquf87n8o/Dictionary%20append%20to%20key.playground.zip?dl=1

Comment: @LeoDabus You were introducing a new generic placeholder `K` which shadowed the `Key` placeholder, additionally you need to constrain `Value` to being a `RangeReplaceableCollection` (so you can append), and you cannot use an array literal, as it may not be `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`. Take a look at http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5a01e7ad9ce6876bc6920dc4

Comment: @Hamish Thanks you so much.

Comment: @LeoDabus A more generalised version of efficiently mutating a dictionary value could look like this: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5a01e9449ce6876bc6920dc6. Although this will be redundant once `subscript(_:default:)` (hopefully!) supports direct mutation via an addressor.

Comment: @Hamish The last one is really amazing. Again thank you so much for the precise feedback

Comment: @LeoDabus No worries – I enjoy this stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's documentation

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and
>   values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering. Each
>   value is associated with a unique key, which acts as an identifier for
>   that value within the dictionary. **Unlike items in an array, items in
>   a dictionary do not have a specified order**. You use a dictionary
>   when you need to look up values based on their identifier, in much the
>   same way that a real-world dictionary is used to look up the
>   definition for a particular word.

Further information is available on [Apple's Website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

**Workaround**

One thing that could be done is to create an array of sorted keys and then use that array to access the dictionary values

Comment: Thanks for the answers: I understand sort on Swift Dictionary is not working but I want a work around to sort Dictionary by key to pass it to TableView.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Is that clear enough or do you want more clarification?

Comment: It is clear but I am still working to fix the problem. Thanks